# If irreversible process is quasistatic then can we find it's work using $pdv$ formula?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility

Now it's given on Wikipedia that quasistatic process can be irreversible,so can I find the work done by the closed system undergoing a process using $pdv$ work?...Next, is that work less than the reversible process undergoing the same process? If yes then how and if no then how?

Answer (score 1):

In the wiki article, they discuss friction as a source of irreversibility.  This would typically involve friction between the piston and the cylinder.  If your "system" is defined as the combination of gas plus piston (so that the friction is occurring within the system), then the process experienced by this system is not reversible.  And, of course, the work done by this system on its surroundings quasi statically (at the outside face of the piston) is not PdV.

But if your "system" is defined as just the gas, then the process experienced by this system is considered reversible in terms of what the gas experiences. (It experiences the exact same deformation and heat history as in a fully reversible process). And, in this case, the work done by the system on its surroundings quasi statically (at the inside face of the piston) is PdV.  And, in this case, the gas is also receiving heat from its surroundings (the piston), assuming all the frictional heat generated goes into the piston, which then transfers heat to the gas (quasi statically).

So, in short, it all depends on what you call your system.  In the first case, all the entropy generation takes place inside the piston.  In the second case, all the entropy generation takes place outside the system.

Comment: Isn't the Pdv work more without friction than with friction, regardless of whether you consider only the gas to be the system vs the gas plus the piston/cylinder being the system?

Comment: @Bob D Not in my judgment.  If the friction is outside of what you are calling your system, the work (which is done by your system at the interface with its surroundings) is PdV (for quasi static).

Comment: But doesn't the work done by the gas consist of both friction work, which raises the temperature of the piston/cylinder contact surfaces and then transfers heat to the gas, plus the PdV work which is the only work that crosses the boundary to the surroundings? I would think the friction work comes at the expense of the PdV work. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Bob D, there is no friction work done by the gas. The gas raises in temperature if it is compressed, but this is not friction.

Comment: @Drew I am thinking about an expansion, not compression. It is the gas pushing on the piston that encounters sliding friction with the cylinder walls. That increases the temperature of the contacting surfaces above the temperature of the gas. Then heat is transferred from the contacting surfaces to the gas.

Comment: @Bob D If you do a force balance on the piston, it is given by $$PA-f=F$$where P is the force of the gas on the inside face of the piston and F is the imposed force on the outside face of the piston (to allow quasi static deformation).  Multiplying this by the displacement gives $$PdV=dW_f+dW_F$$So, if the piston is included in the system, the work done by the system is $$dW_F=PdV-dW_f$$; but, if only the gas is included in the system, the work done by the system is $$PdV=dW_f+dW_F$$

Comment: @Bob D, if you have piston/cylinder friction then yes, there is heat generated at the wall. There are 2 cases in which the gas still undergoes a reversible process: (1) the expansion is much faster than the heat transfer, so that no heat is transferred during the expansion process, and (2) the expansion is so slow that the heat transfer at each infinitesimal stage uniformly raises the gas temperature. In both cases, we can use $pdv$ work, assuming the fast expansion in (1) doesn't break the sound barrier and result in non-uniform pressure.

Comment: @Drew I totally disagree with your characterization of a rapid expansion as a reversible process.  In such a process, there is significant viscous friction within the gas, and the work on the piston face cannot be expressed as PdV, with P being determined by the equation of state (e.g., the ideal gas law).  There is also an anisotropic viscous stress present at the piston face over and above the ideal gas pressure that contributes to the work done by the gas.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Force balance on piston approach very helpful, but I need to give it more thought, especially in the case of a non-quasi static process involving mechanical friction, such as an adiabatic constant pressure expansion. But I'll save that for another day. Thanks!

Comment: @Chester Miller, I guess I'm used to neglecting viscous friction, because it's hard to analytically incorporate and probably negligible. If the expansion timescale is faster than the thermal diffusion timescale, then the adiabatic approximation holds. If we're still slow enough to use $PdV$, however, then the process is reversible if we neglect friction.

Comment: @BobD A non-quais static process such as adiabatic constant pressure expansion is not reversible.  There is viscous entropy generation within the gas during the process.

Comment: @Chester Miller,so how can we find the work in case of an irreversible process?

Comment: @Drew Like I said, in an irreversible expansion, viscous friction precisely accounts for the difference between the process being reversible and the process being irreversible (assuming adiabatic).  It is the viscous friction which gives rise to the entropy generation.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes I know it's not reversible, but neither is the quasi-static process with mechanical friction. Don't both mechanical friction and viscous friction increase entropy? If an irreversible adiabatic constant pressure process,  which is non quasi-static, results in less work than a reversible adiabatic process and the reason is viscous friction, than why doesn't an irreversible quasi-static process involving mechanical friction result in less work than a reversible quasi-static process? I guess that's my conundrum that I'll have to figure out.

Comment: In an irreversible process, unless we are willing to solve the non-linear partial differential Naiver Stokes equations in combination with the continuity equation and the differential thermal energy balance equation within the system, all we can do is control (i.e., impose) the external pressure on the system manually as a function of time (e.g., using an automatic control system or a constant pressure external atmosphere).   So this is the nature of the way that the work is going to specified in problems that we encounter in thermo courses.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Wow, you've given me a lot to think about. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD As I said, it depends on what you define as your system.  If your system consists only of the gas, then the entropy generation from mechanical friction occurs outside the system, and, if your system includes both the gas and the piston, the entropy generation from mechanical friction occurs inside the system.  In the first case, the frictional work on the piston is converted to heat which is then transferred to the system.  In the second case, there is no heat transferred, and the frictional work reduces the work done by the system.  Of course, the two situations are equivalent.

Comment: @ChesterMillerI’ve given you comments a lot of thought. Maybe we should continue this in chat, but consider the following thought experiment. Two insulated piston/cylinders contain an identical ideal gas under compression with a weighted piston. One involves dry friction between the piston and cylinder and the other does not. Half the weight is abruptly removed from each piston allowing the gas in each to expand irreversibly.

Comment: @ChesterMillerAfter the gas in each reaches thermal and mechanical equilibrium the change in height of each piston is measured. Will the change in height (work done by the gas) be the same? Does it matter if we define the system as the gas only, or as the gas plus the piston? Your thoughts?

Comment: @BobD It can't matter, because there is only one unique answer to the problem.  The change in internal energy of the gas is the same in both cases, but the partitioning between heat and work in the two two ways of looking at it are different.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I know it can't matter. That part of question was meant to be rhetorical. The question is, will both weights reach the same height?

Comment: @BobD I would like to pursue this in greater detail, but not here.  It is too restrictive to discussions with many equations and extended length.  Would you be willing to continue in another forum?  If so, I will make a suggestion as to where to continue.

Comment: @BobD OK.  I'll start a post at Physics Forums in the General Physics forum when I have a chance, and we will be able to discuss it there.

Comment: @BobD https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermodynamics-gas-expansion-with-piston-friction.963282/

Comment: @ChesterMiller Happy New Year! Can I use MathJax on the forum?

Comment: @Bob D  I don't think so.  PF is LaTex based.  Using LaTex is pretty easy, and they have a tutorial on the site.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Getting ready to post something, but will be using LaTex for first time. Tried putting in something but it doesn't seem to show me what it will look like before posting it (like the stack exchange does). If I post it will I have an opportunity to edit it? Not sure how this works. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD Hit Review button to see what it looks like.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I don't see a review button. Do I have to hit the post reply button first? Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: @BobD There is an existing thread that I started at the link shown above. Just respond at that link. What is your username on PF? And I meant Preview, not Review.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Not a member of PF. Guess I need to sign up. See the thread and an "add your comments" box at the end. But don't see any preview button.

Comment: @Bob D I guess you need to join up.

Comment: @bobD Hi.  I'm still looking for your first post.  Anything I can do to help?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Have been working on it. I will be posting it today. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @ChesterMiller FYI I posted yesterday and again today with an update after thinking about the original post. Still trying to figure out how to create a profile (discussing with Greg now).